# Add custom column to identify table during query

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-5, accessor

How can I add a custom column in an Eloquent select query in order to identify the table?

For example, I have the current query:

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', getUserID())
    ->get();
```

I'd like to add a column `is_post` with value `1` (for true) *during* the query.

The `Post` class:

```
<?php

class Post extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'posts';

}
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Can you add your Post class to the code? It would be a great help for understanding the problem.

Comment: @miiiiiitchko Added, but it won't help you. :P

Comment: try using ->selectRaw('*, 1 as is_post') before the ->get() statement edit: nvm; i was beaten to it :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do it for example this way:

```
$posts = Post::where('user_id', getUserID())->selectRaw('*, 1 AS `is_post`')->get();
```

but depending on your needs, you can also use the piece of code you showed:

$posts = Post::where('user_id', getUserID())->get();

and add [accessor](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) in `Post` model this way:

```
public function getIsPostAttribute($value) {
  return 1;
}
```

In both cases you should be able to display `is_post` value for example this way:

```
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  echo $post->is_post;
}
```